# CSS Bootstrap Button Modifications

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to edit a bootstrap button and add a 10px margin-bottom to the class .btn. However, my edits are loading. If I do it via inline-html (EX. style="margin-bottom: 10px") it works, but I'd prefer to stick to best coding practices and not do that. Help would be greatly appreciated

CSS

```
.no-gutters {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.btn {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
{% block styles %}
{{ super() }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

<h3>Productivity</h3>
      <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 py-1">
             <button class="btn btn-warning" data-criteria="wifi" data-toggle="button">
                 <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wifi"></i>
                 <br>
                 <span title="Stable Wi-Fi">
                  Wi-Fi
                 </span>
              </button>
     </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/),  Assign responsive-friendly margin or padding values to an element or a subset of its sides with shorthand classes. I suggest you use bootstrap's shorthand notation classes like the `mb-0` which makes `margin-bottom:0` Depending on the screen size, the actual value may vary. Consider the following:

**Notation**
Spacing utilities that apply to all breakpoints, from xs to xl, have no breakpoint abbreviation in them. This is because those classes are applied from min-width: 0 and up, and thus are not bound by a media query. The remaining breakpoints, however, do include a breakpoint abbreviation.

The classes are named using the format `{property}{sides}-{size} for xs` and `{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}` for `sm, md, lg,` and `xl`.

Where property is one of:

`m` - for classes that set margin
`p` - for classes that set padding
Where sides is one of:

`t` - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
`b` - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
`l` - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left
`r` - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right
`x` - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
`y` - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
`blank` - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element
*Where size is one of*:

0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
auto - for classes that set the margin to auto
(You can add more sizes by adding entries to the $spacers Sass map variable.)

Comment: Thank you for the help!!!! I also had to do a hard refresh with Shift+F5 to help clear cache and reload css.

Comment: Welcome, Shift + f5 is another idea to ensure you are working with the actual resources.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your browser if is taken the css correctly.

if it is and no taking the style you can add the !important on your style.

example:

```
.btn {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```